# Dummy variable of the integral

Tags: integration

Let's say $r(t)$ represents people per hour in line for cinema ticket.
While integrating $r(t)$ from $t=0$ to $t=t$ to find people in the line, why we need to change $r(t)$ into different variable and different dummy variable like $r$$(s)$ with $ds$ or $r(x)$ with $dx$. Why using $dt$ with $r(t)$ would be wrong if I am integrating lower bound $0$ to upper bound $t$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing $\int_0^t r(t) \, dt$ is not correct, because you have the variable $t$ appearing with two different meanings: $t$ is both the upper limit in your integral and the variable of integration.  In this case it's fairly anodyne, but in general, it can cause confusion.  For example, say you define $f(t) = \int_0^t t^2 \, dt$. Then what is $f(3)$?  Naively replacing the $t$'s in the expression with $3$'s gives you something like $\int_0^3 3^2 \, dt$ which is presumably not what you want.  Define $f(t) = \int_0^t s^2 \, ds$ and then $f(3) = \int_0^3 s^2 \, ds$ as you would expect.

Or, what is $t \int _0^t t^2 \, dt$? If the $t$ on the outside means the upper limit of the integral, which is a constant, then you can push it inside the integral to get $\int_0^t t^3 \, dt = t^4 / 4$. Or is it $(t) (t^3 / 3) = t^4 / 3$?  Better to write $t \int_0^t s^2 \, ds$.